# ng-if does not add behaviour while ng-show does

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Case :**

```
<div class="slide" ng-show="condition" >
```

I have a directive set as class that gives the slide behavior to the div when it shows.
 
When i use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` so that the code does not get executed unless the condition really applies, the slide behavior is not working anymore, while with `ng-show` it works .

Is there a work around this? timeout maybe?

```
<div class="slide" ng-if="condition" >
```

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet of your directive then we can know how it works.

Comment: added please check @Rebornix

Answer (score 1):

This is as expected. ngIf animations are defined differently than ngShow animations.

The proper way to do animations is to include the [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module and then include animations CSS for each of the directives you want to animate (like [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf#animations), [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#animations), [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations)).

```
/* ng-if */
.slide.ng-enter, 
.animate-if.ng-leave {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.slide.ng-leave,
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

/* ng-show */
.slide {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.slide.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.slide.ng-hide {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}
```

Comment: i see but this code dos not allow my animation directive behavior you have created your own slide . I have added it the code please check

Comment: I was wondering if i can add some timout to let it include my animations @Blaise

Comment: You're mixing jQuery with Angular, but Angular does not work that way. You should read up on how AngularJS animations work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 <div ng-class="{slide: true}" ng-if="condition" >
```

Comment: try this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate try solution under title "JavaScript-based Animations"